# C++ equivalent of scala's Seq.grouped?

Tags: c++, scala, collections

I would like to use an idiomatic (std::algorithm or similar) version of Scala's `.grouped` in C++. This breaks a sequence into groups of size `N` where the last group may be smaller. Any ideas?

Reference: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator%5BC%5D

I've successfully used a loop with `std::min` but I would like something built in. This is my solution for grouping into chunks of 7 (found here on SO in another answer):

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> chunked;
std::vector<uint64_t> flat;

// group into chunks of 7
for (size_t i = 0; i < flat.size(); i += 7) {
    auto last = std::min(flat.size(), i + 7);
    std::vector<uint64_t> chunk =std::vector<uint64_t>(flat.begin() + i, flat.begin() + last);
    chunked.emplace_back(chunk);
}
```

Comment: How's `std::min` not a _"built in"_? Elaborate your question please.

Comment: how does `std::min` help to implement this? It would really help if you would post your code that works sucessfully and explain what you want to change about it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP means to have a method that does the job in stdlib, without having to code it himself. To give more context Scala stdlib is quite rich and it's quite rare to have to implement manually such a method.

Comment: Judging from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942869/divide-container-into-chunks-c) the thing you are looking for does not exist. To be fair, the question 10+ years old, so,  could be that it got added since then.

Comment: I think [std::views::chunk](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_view) (since C++23) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys. not sure why this got closed, but these comments answer my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::ranges::views::chunk](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_view) would do the job (but is only available "since" C++23).